# String format for dictionary with f-strings

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, f-string

I have a dictionary and I want to print the key and values of this in f-strings format.

**Sample 1:**

```
dic = {'A': 1, 'B': 2}
Output: "This is output A:1 B:2"
```

**Sample 2:**

```
dic = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
Output: "This is output A:1 B:2 C:3"
```

I would like to request a general answer so that I could add more key-value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate through the key-value pairs, and print the output accordingly:

```
dic = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
print('This is output', end=' ')
for k,v in dic.items():
    print(str(k) + ':' + str(v), end=' ')
```

Output

```
This is output A:1 B:2 C:3
```

Alternatively you could concatenate the string (same output):

```
dic = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
s = ''
for k,v in dic.items():
    s += f'{k}:{v} '   #thanks to @blueteeth
print('This is output', s.strip())
```

Comment: Just a note that good practice to use f-strings. So it would be `s += f"{k}:{v} "`

Comment: Nice! I'd edit it to my answer.. thanks for the helpful input

Answer (score 3):

Try join()

```
'This is output ' + ' '.join(f'{key}:{value}' for key, value in dic.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need -

```py
d = {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}
print("This is output ")
for key, value in d.items():
    print(f"{key}:{value}", end=" ")
```